# Set Delegate Programmatically for a UIScrollView in .xib

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a UIView in my .xib file. (note that not a UIControlView)

```
@interface OfferUIView : UIView
```

So the custom class for my UIView is OfferUIView

I want to add a scrollView to it. when I add it using xcode features, I just connect the delegate of scrollview to OfferUIView. How can I do it programmatically in OfferUIView.m?

This is what I dit :

```
self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame: frame];
self.scrollView.delegate = self;
```

But I get a warning on the `delegate = self` like this:

```
Assigning to id<UIScrollViewDelegate> from incompatible type OfferUIView
```

Do you know how can I fix it?

Edit:

when I use

```
@interface OfferUIView : UIView <UIScrollViewDelegate>

self.pageViews = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < pageCount; ++i) {
        [self.pageViews addObject:[NSNull null]];
    }

    CGRect frame = self.view.bounds;
    self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame: frame];
    CGSize pagesScrollViewSize = self.view.frame.size;
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(pagesScrollViewSize.width * self.pageImages.count, pagesScrollViewSize.height);
    self.scrollView.delegate = self;
```

It should be couple of images in UIScrollView, but scroll does not work.

Comment: in yourView Controller just put this <UIScrollViewDelegate>

Comment: Thanks, please check my edit at the end of the question.

Comment: You are placing scrollview through xib rite ? If it is so then remove this self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame: frame];

Comment: No, I created it programmatically. check the code.

Comment: review this link..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8909347/implementing-uiscrollview-programmatically

Comment: did u placed in the view [self.view addSubview:self.scrollView] ??

Comment: YES I do @Venkat Manohar

Comment: Hello @Ali: Could you please print the array description. Cause, if your array count == 0 then ScrollView ContentSize width will be 0

Comment: I put easily a number there like 3. Does not work :)

Answer (score 3):

You have to specify that your class should conform to [UIScrollViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#Documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html).

```
@interface OfferUIView : UIView <UIScrollViewDelegate>
```

Comment: I did that the warning become disapear but the scrollView does not work. check my edit in the end of question.

Comment: @Ali What is the scroll view's `contentSize` set to, and is it a greater size than the scroll view's frame?

Comment: As you see in my edit, I set the contentSize, It works when I set it from apple features but not programmatically, can you find out what is wrong?

Comment: what do you mean by this "apple features" @Ali?

Comment: It is possible to set content size programmatically.Your content size must be greater than your scrollview's frame size in order to see the scrolling

Comment: I think you need to see the code that I added to the end of the question. ContetnSize

Answer (score 3):

```
scrollView =[[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 402, 750, 600)];
scrollView.delegate = self;
scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES; 
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(654, ([reports_list count]+1)*110)];
```

It Worked for me... Just Try it.. And Ignore the frames.